# How to insert all rows of Excel into a db table when column index's are in a variable when using xlrd and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql-9.1, xlrd

I am working with xlrd, Python, and Postgres.
I pull data from Excels using xlrd and insert into a postgres database table.
I understand using index numbers per each column header, but there is 1 Excel where the column index numbers change(Meaning the data for column A would show in column A one day, but will switch to a different column on a different day). So instead of using the column index number, I am looping the Excel based on the text value for the header names and assigning the column index number to a variable. The issue I am having is: If there are 20 rows of data, the very last row of data from the Excel will insert into the DB table only, and I need all rows inserted.

How am I able to adjust my code so all rows of data inserts into the database table?

All help is greatly appreciated.

```
            import psycopg2
            import xlrd

            try:
                conn = psycopg2.connect(user = 'Username', password = 'Password', host = 'Host_name', database = 'DB_name', port = Port_number)
                mycursor = conn.cursor()

                print('DB connection open')
                print('XLRD Data inserting into DB Table')

                #Open the excel
                book = xlrd.open_workbook('excel_name.xlsx')
                #Use Index # for Which worksheet or use by_sheet_name......
                sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

                #Loop row index's
                for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
                    row = sheet.row(rowidx)
                    #Loop Column index's
                    for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                        #Cell value Text for Header name
                        if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_A":
                            #Varablize header index #
                            header_name_a_index = colidx

                        if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_B":
                            #Varablize header index #
                            header_name_b_index = colidx

                        if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_C":
                            #Varablize header index #
                            header_name_c_index = colidx

                        if cell.value == "Header_Name_Column_D":
                            #Varablize header index #
                            header_name_d_index = colidx

                        #Insert generic values into DB table columns
                        #I have tried moving the sql and excel for loop within the different loops above.
                        sql = """INSERT INTO db_table_name(
                        first_column_name_db,
                        second_column_name_db,
                        third_column_name_db,
                        fourth_column_name_db
                        )

                        VALUES(
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s)"""

                        #loop through all rows and cells
                        for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
                            first_column_name_db = sheet.cell(r, header_name_a_index).value
                            #Index number prints for each row, but only the last row inserts into the db table.
                            print(header_name_a_id_index)
                            second_column_name_db = sheet.cell(r, header_name_b_index).value
                            third_column_name_db = sheet.cell(r, header_name_c_index).value
                            fourth_column_name_db = sheet.cell(r, header_name_d_index).value

                            #Assign values to each row
                            values = (
                            first_column_name_db,
                            second_column_name_db,
                            third_column_name_db,
                            fourth_column_name_db
                            )

                        mycursor.execute(sql, values)

                        #Commit to the DB. Close the mycursor and conn.
                        mycursor.close()
                        #Just a thought - Do I need to commit each row???
                        conn.commit()
                        conn.close()

            except Exception as e:
                #Close cursor and connection if error
                mycursor.close()
                conn.close()
                print('Error')
                print(e)
```

Comment: `mycursor.execute(sql, values)` is _outside_ of the `for` loop. So the `for` loop runs to completion and then you execute your INSERT with whatever it defined at the end of the loop.

Comment: @roganjosh thank you for your comment. I believe the tab got messed up when I pasted in the code. I believe when I tried that on Friday, the last row of the excel was the only row inserting. When I get home, I will try it and post an updated comment.

Comment: @roganjosh I was comparing the test script I have above with the script I am writing and you are correct with one more tab for the mycursor.execute line. The issue with my main Python script was the tab's for the values under the For Loop. They were lined up with the word For in the loop and not inside the loop I should have looked closer at the other For Loops and values I am very new to coding and I did not go to college for software development I am learning on my own by coding and making mistakes I say not bad for picking up Python, postgres, mysql, VB, Java, C++, android in 6 - 8 months